# spring jpa insertable and updatable are not working

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have one jpa entity , similar to

```
public Student {

.....

    @Column(name = "attendStatus" , nullable = true, insertable = false ,updatable = false)
    private UIMappingStatus attendStatus;
.....


}
```

**I want this field when am doing select queries , i mean i want to get the data from this table , only thing is i do not want to insert into , update to this column , as their is no such real column is present**

below the sample select query where this column is dynamically generating

```
SELECT 
  id,
  case when present = 'ABC' then 'XYZ' when present = 'uvw' then 'kml' else null end as attendStatus 
FROM public.service_config where id = '10'
order by attendStatus asc 
limit 
  100;
```

**NOTE : If i use Transient on this field in entity class , then during select queries , the will be assigned to null value**

basically , their is no such column attendStatus in Student table, this column is calculated in native sql query based on the other real columns present in that Student table , select query is working fine , but at some other code places , i saw their are save and saveAndFlush methods being called on the StudentReporsitory class which is JPA repository , their the problem is coming as below

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column student0_.attendStatus does not exist
```

why am getting this error , even i added the attributes

```
insertable = false ,updatable = false
```

can anyone please help me

Tried and search but am not able to find any helpful

**`Update : I am trying to use @Formula as suggested in comments , but how to use sorting and pagination on thse @Formula properties ?`**

Comment: You cannot update/insert it but that doesn't mean you cannot select it. If you don't want this to be part of the entity use `@Transient` or use an `@Formula` to indicate that this is a calculated field.

Comment: as i mentioned i want this during select queries , if i use @Transient, then during select queries null values will assgined for this column

Comment: You are mixing concepts into 1 object don't do things like that. Your entity should contain only fields that are columns in the database, that is how entities work. For calculated fields if you must you can use `@Formula` or if you have a dedicated select for something create a dedicated DTO for that instead of abusing/shoehorning all of that into a single entity/object.

Comment: What is the SQL actually issued for the insert/update that is failing? Could you have mapped this column some other way in this or another entity? This is a strange issue, as the insertable=false, updatable=false should have JPA providers exclude it from the SQL statement, but your hibernate settings must have it try to pass in values for all columns. You might check if there are settings to force hibernate to use dynamic statements - statements for only the changed columns

Answer (score 0):

you need to check 3 things.

1. Check the Table Definition: First, ensure that the Student table in your PostgreSQL database actually contains a column named attendStatus. You can use a database management tool or connect to the database using a PostgreSQL client to inspect the table structure.
2. Check the Database Schema:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student", schema = "public")
public class Student {
    // ...
}
```

3. Check Entity Attribute Name:

```
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {
    // ...

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UIMappingStatus attendStatus;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I clearly mentioned it is calculated property